How to Add Custom Report Button to Sale Order in Odoo?
I'm currently working on a custom Odoo module in Odoo where I want to add a custom report button called "Order Product Summary" to the Sale Order form. The goal is to create a summary report that aggregates the quantities of products across selected orders. I've created a custom module with the following folder structure:
My Code is as Follows:
__manifest__.py
{
    'name': 'Order Product Summary Report',
    'version': '1.0',
    'depends': ['sale'],  
    'data': [
        'report/report_product_summary.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'application': False,
}

sale_order_summary.py
from odoo import models, fields

class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    product_summary_count = fields.Integer(string="Product Summary Count", compute="_compute_product_summary")

    def _compute_product_summary(self):
        for order in self:
            order.product_summary_count = sum(line.product_uom_qty for line in order.order_line)

report_product_summary.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <!-- Report Template -->
    <template id="report_product_summary_template">
        <t t-call="web.external_layout">
            <div class="page">
                <h2>Order Product Summary Report</h2>
                <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <t t-foreach="doc.order_line" t-as="line">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span t-field="line.product_id.name"/></td>
                                <td><span t-field="line.product_uom_qty" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>

    <!-- Report Action -->
    <report
        id="action_report_product_summary"
        string="Order Product Summary"
        model="sale.order"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="order_product_summary_report.report_product_summary_template"
        file="order_product_summary_report.report_product_summary_template"
        print_report_name="'Order Product Summary - %s' % (object.name)"
    />
</odoo>

Despite following the steps to create and register the report button, it does not show up in the Odoo interface.

I have checked for syntax errors in my XML files, ensured that the user has the necessary permissions, and looked at the server logs for any warnings or errors during loading.
I am also unsure if I need to define anything else in my report XML to ensure it is properly registered.

What additional steps should I take to ensure that my custom report button appears in the Sale Order form in Odoo? Are there any common pitfalls or mistakes I should look out for?
Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

it seems to me that your goal should be fulfilled by the inventory App, that manages product quantity according to achieved sales...
